# NoClassDefFoundError when running unit test with Gradle task

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, junit

I have a project using [dynamic feature module](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery), and I want to run my unit test in feature module via gradle task (for my CI purpose):

```
./gradlew :feature_product:test
```

But it always gives me `NoClassDefFoundError` for tests that have dependencies on classes from the base module:

```
com.example.android.feature.product.ProductViewTest > on vote change to negative FAILED
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: app.BaseView
```

`ProductView` class from the feature module extends `BaseView` from the base module.

Oddly, it succeeds when run in Android Studio, it works fine.

[image: android studio]

Then I notice something different in the logs, when I run via command line and when I run Android Studio. The first line in the Android Studio is `generateDebugSources`, something which absent when I run `./gradlew test`

```
Executing tasks: [:lib_ui:generateDebugSources, ...]
```

How do I fix this? Does Android Studio has different command with the provided command `./gradlew test` when I press Ctrl+Shift+R ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. In my case the `dynamic-feature-module` tests can't find any class from the `application-module`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue too, did you guys manage to fix it?

Comment: I manage to run the unit test with gradle by not calling anything in my base module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching further about this issue, I found it also being reported in the [android-test](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/388) and [app-bundle-samples](https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/issues/11) projects and there is also an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139441237) in the issue tracker.

It turns out this issue fixed in the Android Gradle Plugin 4.1.0 as per comment in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139441237).

If you don't want to update AGP to 4.1.0 which is still in alpha, adding this to the feature module's build.gradle fixed the issue for me, as per this [comment](https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/issues/11#issuecomment-640170633):

```
testRuntimeOnly(files("$projectDir/../b_app/build/intermediates/app_classes/debug/classes.jar"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a missing task that you believe is necessary then calling it first like below should do the trick:

```
./gradlew :lib_ui:generateDebugSources :feature_product:test
```

I would even go full on and `assemble` the dependencies if necessary though that might take more time:

```
./gradlew :lib_ui:assemble :feature_product:assemble :feature_product:test
```